# How do you use reduce(into:) in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, reduce

I am reading iOS 13 Programming Fundamentals with Swift, got to the part about reduce() and I think I understand it more or less, but then there is reduce(into:) and this piece of code:

```
let nums = [1,2,3,4,5]
let result = nums.reduce(into: [[],[]]) { temp, i in 
    temp[i%2].append(i)
}
// result is now [[2,4],[1,3,5]]
```

So this code takes an array of Int and splits it into 2 arrays, even and odd. The problem is that I have no idea what's happening inside the brackets {}.

In the case of reduce, the first parameter is the first one of the iteration and then the closure is supposed to process all the items one after the other, similar to map() but more powerful (here one loop is enough to get the two arrays but with map() I would need 2 loops, according to the book).

I cannot understand the syntax here anyway, especially what does "temp" stand for and that use of "in". And how is "append()" appending the value to the proper array??

Comment: Hmm, so I would have to explain my own explanation?

Comment: `temp` is `[[],[]]` when we start, and it changes each time thru the loop because we append to one of the inner arrays. And at the end it is assigned to `result`.

Comment: And `i%2` is 0 if `i` is even and 1 if it is odd. Do you see? That’s how we decide which inner array to append to.

Comment: Have you checked out the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126956-reduce)? The declaration should explain the variables pretty clearly. And since the `in` syntax confuses you, you should probably also in general check the [closure](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html) part of the Swift book.

Comment: If you really want “to know what every variable / label stands for during the loop and how the values change”, step thru on paper or use the debugger and watch the variables change.

Comment: @matt and @MassimilianoBartolini Does the book not introduce introduce the closure syntax before this? If it did, you should know that `{ ... }` is a closure and `temp` is one of its parameters.

Comment: @Sweeper of course. If we assume a knowledge of all pages prior to this one, there can be no question. It’s as if the OP had skipped the whole book and jumped to this point (and then read the code but not the words describing it).

Comment: @matt woah sorry for asking

Comment: Well I’m just defending my presentation in the book. Sweeper asked whether I had explained the syntax before this point and I said yes. Gosh, I gave you a personal complete explanation, I thought you’d be happy.

Comment: @matt my apologizing for asking was not sarcastic, I usually try to avoid asking for help unless I am really confused (this was my first question ever on Stack Overflow) and I feel kinda ashamed I don’t get this things faster.
Anyway now I understand the function, thanks for the explanation. There are a lot of concepts and I’ll need to read the book at least one more time before starting the next volume. Regards,

Comment: Well my explanation wasn’t sarcastic either. I really tried to make it clearer. I’m happy if I succeeded. Just be aware that questions of the form “What is Matt Neuburg saying here” are likely to be answered by Matt Neuburg telling you what he’s saying.

Comment: @MassimilianoBartolini Don't add "solved" to your question. If the question is answered without an actual answer being given, the best approach is to delete it, which you are free to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the closure, "temp" is the result format which is [[][]] and "i" is each number. As you said it processes all numbers in a loop. When % is used it returns the division remainder, so for the odd numbers like "1,3,5", it returns "1" and for the even numbers "0", which means that "temp" appends these values to the array in these respective indexes.

So if we debug and replace the variables for constants the results would be:

```
temp[1].append(1) //1%2 = 1/2 left 1 [[][1]]
temp[0].append(2) //2%2 = 2/2 left 0 [[2][1]]
temp[1].append(3) //3%2 = 3/2 = 1 left 1 [[2][1,3]]
temp[0].append(4) //4%2 = 4/2 left 0 [[2,4][1,3]]
temp[1].append(5) //5%2 = 5/2 = 2 left 1 [[2,4][1,3,5]]
```

According to the documentation the closure is called sequentially with a mutable accumulating value initialized that when exhausted, is returned to the caller.